# selecting unique ids from two rows

Tags: mysql, sql

ok so table looks like this

```
owner_id | creator_id | receiver_id | content | created
1        | 1          | 2           | hoho    | 2011-27-05
2        | 1          | 2           | hoho    | 2011-27-05
1        | 2          | 1           | eoeo    | 2011-28-05
2        | 2          | 1           | eoeo    | 2011-28-05
1        | 1          | 3           | aaaa    | 2011-29-05
3        | 1          | 3           | aaaa    | 2011-29-05
2        | 2          | 3           | bbbb    | 2011-30-05
3        | 2          | 3           | bbbb    | 2011-30-05
```

what I would like is to select only the last record for owner_id = 1 from each creator_id OR receiver_id and it doesn't matter is it last from creator_id or receiver_id as long it is last record where unique creator_id or receiver_id is.

do the result should look like this

```
owner_id | creator_id | receiver_id | content | created
1        | 1          | 3           | aaaa    | 2011-29-05
1        | 2          | 1           | eoeo    | 2011-28-05
```

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question. It's hard to know what you're actually asking here.

Comment: mybe I should say what i dont want and that is I dont want to have duplicate values for creator_id and receiver_id except for value 1 which is owner's id, so creator_id and receiver_id should be different allways it doesnt matter if id is in creator_id or receiver_id row, hope this helps

Comment: You also have to define what "last" means. Tables don't have an inherent order unless there's an ORDER BY clause. So how are you sorting your table?

Comment: Perhaps?: The last (ordered `by created(date)`) two records `where owner_id=1` and `creator_id <> receiver_id` ?

Comment: yes but it should be only last from each id in receiver_id and creator_id row

Comment: Oh OK, you want unique `creator_id` and unique `receiver_id` where `creator = 1`, yes?

Comment: @tim rogers: last should also be last record from each id ordered by created

Comment: What do you mean with last **from each**? If there are two rows with `receiver_id=2` and two rows with `creator_id=3`, the query should show these 4 rows?

Comment: I'm downvoting you for the most confusing question ever.

Comment: @billynomates: something like that, I want unique creator_id and receiver_id but then the other value should allways be 1, so if creator_id = 2 then owner_id = 1 and receiver_id = 1, other option if receiver_id = 2 then owner_id should be 1 and creator_id = 1

Comment: @billynomates: And even more confusing comments!

Comment: @billynomates: sorry, but result table that I posted in question explains it perfectly

Comment: I think I understand now and if I'm right, then Denis' solution should work.

Comment: @billynomates: :) hm Denis's solution is close but not really, i get message Column 'owner_id' in where clause is ambiguous, and withoud that last where owner_id = 12 it still displays multiple records form ids...

Answer (score 2):

Start by fetching the last date per owner_id, creator_id:

```
select owner_id,
       creator_id as user_id,
       max(created) as max_created
from data
where owner_id = 1
group by owner_id, creator_id
```

And the same per owner_id, receiver_id:

```
select owner_id,
       receiver_id as user_id,
       max(created) as max_created
from data
where owner_id = 1
group by owner_id, receiver_id
```

Then union and apply the max another time:

```
select owner_id, user_id, max(max_created) as max_created
from (
     [the first of the above]
     union all
     [the second of the above]
     ) as users
group by owner_id, user_id
```

Then join it in a subquery:

```
select data.*
from data
join ([the union query above]) as max_dates
on max_dates.owner_id = data.owner_id
and max_dates.user_id in (data.creator_id, data.reporter_id)
and max_dates.max_created = data.created
where owner_id = 1 -- avoids scanning the whole table
```

That'll yield the rows where creator_id appeared last, and those where reporter_id appeared last.

You cannot reduce it further without dropping valid rows. Suppose the returned (creator/reporter) pairs are (1,2) and (2,1). Then both rows would be eliminated if you sought the absolute last appearance of each user.

Comment: ok, with some modifications I managed to do it, this is great, thank you!